# How to have the configuration name in the bit file that can be read back after flashing the bit file on to the fpga?

Tags: fpga

I have 2 bit files say Config_1.bit and Config_2.bit. I would like to have the name of the bit file inside the bit file along with the design because when I would want to know what bit file is already present on FPGA before using the FPGA.Any suggestions or ideas are highly welcome.

Ex: Lets say I have flashed config_1.bit on to the FPGA. Now I want to see the name of the design on my Hyper terminal before running any application.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Altera's approach is to instantiate the "System ID peripheral" that stores timestamp and 32-bit numeric ID that is pre-set during IP configuration.

You would read that peripheral, either via jtag (this way Nios SBT is checking if the software is compiled for the right system), or embedded system would read it and report through uart/spi/i2c - whatever you will be using with terminal.